# Передача html-кода через ajax

Tags: ajax, html, javascript, php

Добрый день! У меня возникла такая проблема, я формирую таблицу данных средствами php в файле select.php. Как мне сформированный html-код передать на главную страницу index.php средствами ajax, тоесть без перезагрузки страницы.

Вот файл **select.php**:

```
<?php
   // достаем из базы данных ID и заголовок всех статей
   $result = $connect->query("select article_id, article_title from article ORDER BY article_title");
   //определяем количество полученных записей
   $colResult = $result->num_rows;

   if($colResult > 0)
   {
      for($i = 0; $i < $colResult; $i++)
      {
         $row = $result->fetch_object();
         echo"<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$row->article_id."</td>";
         echo "<td><span name='text_title[".$row->article_id."]'>".$row->article_title."</span>
        <input type='text' name='edit_title[".$row->article_id."]' value='".$row->article_title."' style='display:none'></td>";
        echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='check_button' value='".$row->article_id."'></center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
      }
   }    
?>
```

А на главной странице (**index.php**) примерно так в простейшем случае:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<script>
// получаем AJAX запрос
          $.ajax(
        {
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: {Как тут принять html-данные?},
                success: function() 
        {

                }
             }
     );
</script>
</table>
</body>
```

Как отобразить html-данные между тегами `<table></table>` сформированными на странице select.php? Ajax и JS почти не знаю, потому прошу помощи у опытных в этом деле программистов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общих чертах как то так:

```
<html>
<head><title>Some title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="data-box">
    <tr><td>Loading...</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'select.php', success: function(response){
                    $('#data-box').html(response);
                 }
          });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Олег! Это как раз то что нужно мне! Вопрос только такой когда будет выполняться $(document).ready? При загрузке только страницы или постоянно, когда хоть произошли малейшие изменения в таблице?

Comment: "документ реди" это когда страница загружена и готов DOM, к Вашей таблице не имеет отношения.

Comment: Мне просто хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы в базе происходили изменения, а пользователь через страницу index.php в реальном времени видел эти изменения.

Comment: Можно ajax запрос поставить на setInterval но это катастрофически забьёт Ваш сервер, если делать это по уму нужно использовать сокеты, но это не просто, если у вас проблемы с настройкой AJAX с сокетами будет разобраться порядком сложнее. Сделайте кнопку "обновить данные" и на неё повесить аякс запрос